# SQL exclude inner join table

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have a table that has 2 columns that I'm concerned with

```
Business_ID   /   Product type
```

I am trying to write a SQL query to only get businesses that sell one type, but not the others. So the table is populated with

```
B_ID    prod_type
123  |   A
123  |   A
123  |   B
234  |   A
234  |   C
234  |   C
456  |   A
456  |   D
789  |   A
```

and the list goes on and on. I am trying to write a SQL statement that will find a B_ID that sells prod_type A and not prod_type B, C, D. Here is what I'm trying but it doesn't work

```
SELECT phop_1.Business_id, phop_1.PRODUCT_TYPE, count(*) 
FROM phop phop_1, phop phop_2
WHERE phop_1.Business_id = phop_2.Business_id
  AND phop_1.PRODUCT_TYPE = 'A'
  AND NOT phop_2.PRODUCT_TYPE = 'B'
GROUP BY phop_1.Business_id, phop_1.PRODUCT_TYPE
```

I also found how to exclude using an outer join, but since it's the same table I can't do that unless there is a way to select out the prod_type A before doing the join.

```
select phop_1.Business_id, phop_1.PRODUCT_TYPE, count(*) 
from phop phop_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN phop phop_2
ON phop_1.Business_id = phop_2.Business_id
WHERE phop_2.Business_id IS NULL
GROUP BY phop_1.Business_id, phop_1.PRODUCT_TYPE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.BusinessId
FROM phop p
   LEFT JOIN phop p2 ON p.BusinessId = p2.BusinessId AND p2.Product_Type <> 'A'
WHERE p2.BusinessId IS NULL
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2eb28/2).

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Select businesses with only one product type first, then join it against your original table.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
    (
     B_ID INT,
     prod_type VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT  INTO @tbl
        (B_ID, prod_type)
VALUES  (123, 'A'),
        (123, 'A'),
        (123, 'B'),
        (234, 'A'),
        (234, 'C'),
        (234, 'C'),
        (456, 'A'),
        (456, 'D'),
        (789, 'A') ;

WITH    businessIdsWithOneProductType
          AS (SELECT    B_ID
              FROM      @tbl t
              GROUP BY  B_ID
              HAVING    COUNT(DISTINCT prod_type) = 1)
    SELECT  *
    FROM    businessIdsWithOneProductType
            INNER JOIN @tbl ON businessIdsWithOneProductType.B_ID = [@tbl].B_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN tableName b
            ON a.B_ID = b.B_ID AND
                b.prod_type IN ('B','C','D')
WHERE b.B_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dbf7/6)